# потоковое обновление html данных в окне pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, сигналы-слоты, qthread

Есть программка, которая  в отдельном потоке постоянно обновляет данные в `label`.

Хочу сделать так чтобы эти данные были цветными. Но при попытке отправить `html` текст на окно, программа дропается (windows считает что программа свое отработала и предлагает её закрыть). Попытки отловить ошибку к успеху не привели.

Для примера:

```py
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class Trd(QThread):
    def __init__(self, parent, function):
        super(Trd, self).__init__(parent)
        self.function = function
    def run(self):self.function()

class Win(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Win, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 300, 100)

        self.label = QLabel(self)
        self.label.setGeometry(0, 0, 100, 100)
        self.label.setText('TEXT')

        self.show()

        trd = Trd(self, self.update_label)
        trd.start()

    def update_label(self):
        lines = ['<font color="red">RED</font>',
                 '<font color="blue">BLUE</font>',
                 '<font color="green">GREEN</font>']
        # lines = ['RED',
        #          'BLUE',
        #          'GREEN']

        while True:
            for i in range(len(lines)):
                self.label.setText(lines[i])
                QThread.sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    application = Win()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Если использовать код в комментарии - программа не дропнется и будет работать. В гугле не нашел информации по этому поводу. Намекните мне, что я делаю не так?

Comment: Уточните в вопросе, что значит *программа дропается*. Например, приведите возникающую ошибку.

Comment: Не используйте объекты одного потока в другом. В отдельном потоке через сигналы отправляйте данные

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нельзя использовать объекты основного потока в дополнительных потоках, это не безопасно! Надо использовать сигналы и слоты, примерно так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *


class Trd(QThread):
    newColorSignal = pyqtSignal(str)
    
    def __init__(self, parent): 
        super(Trd, self).__init__(parent)
        self.lines = ['<font color="red">RED</font>',
                 '<font color="blue">BLUE</font>',
                 '<font color="green">GREEN</font>']
        
    def run(self):
        i = 0
        while True:
            self.newColorSignal.emit(self.lines[i])
            i = i + 1 if i < 2 else 0
            self.sleep(1)
        

class Win(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Win, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 300, 100)

        self.label = QLabel(self)
        self.label.setGeometry(0, 0, 100, 100)
        self.label.setText('TEXT')

        self.show()

        self.trd = Trd(self) #, self.update_label)
        self.trd.newColorSignal.connect(self.update_label)
        self.trd.start()

    def update_label(self, text):
        self.label.setText(text)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QFont("Times", 16, QFont.Bold))
    application = Win()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Кст, можно через деление по модулю сделать обнуление, например: `i = (i + 1) % len(self.lines)` или использовать модуль `itertools.cycle`

Comment: @gil9red  можно :)

Comment: а можно ли сделать так, чтобы можно было использовать класс Trd многократно? т.е к примеру у меня много окон и столько же массивов данных для обновления к этим окнам, так не создавать же мне столько же классов с привязкой только одного массива данных к одному окну? надеюсь, что понятно изложил суть вопроса)   п.с вот как например в моем коде, я конечно понимаю что у меня не правильно, но хотелось бы сохранить идею

Comment: @Владимир Все можно. Вы задали вопрос,  я предложил решение. Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour  Если у вас есть другие вопросы - задайте их, сформировав новый вопрос.