# QObject::setParent: Cannot set parent, new parent is in a different thread

Tags: python, многопоточность, pyqt5

Появляется ошибка при появлении нового письма. Я создаю почтовый сервис рандомных почт на базе mail.tm, после получения письма на почту выходит ошибка `QObject::setParent: Cannot set parent, new parent is in a different thread`, я понимаю что вероятнее всего ошибка из-за того что я использую потоки, но не знаю как ее решить. Вот сам код:

```
import sys
import typing
from mailtm import Email
import os
import requests
import json
import threading
import time
import shutil


from PyQt5 import QtCore, uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QSlider, QLineEdit, QLabel, QPushButton, QScrollArea,QApplication,
                             QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QMainWindow)
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Temp_Mail(object):
    def setupUi(self, Temp_Mail):
        Temp_Mail.setObjectName("Temp_Mail")
        Temp_Mail.resize(1280, 720)
        Temp_Mail.setInputMethodHints(QtCore.Qt.ImhNone)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Temp_Mail)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.textBrowser = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView(self.centralwidget)
        self.textBrowser.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 60, 941, 641))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Monaco")
        self.textBrowser.setFont(font)
        self.textBrowser.setAccessibleName("")
        self.textBrowser.setStyleSheet("border: 2px, solid black")
        self.textBrowser.setObjectName("textBrowser")
        self.Inbox_text = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.Inbox_text.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 10, 321, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Monaco")
        font.setPointSize(25)
        self.Inbox_text.setFont(font)
        self.Inbox_text.setToolTip("")
        self.Inbox_text.setStyleSheet("")
        self.Inbox_text.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.Inbox_text.setObjectName("Inbox_text")
        self.RefreshButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.RefreshButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1180, 0, 71, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Monaco")
        font.setPointSize(40)
        self.RefreshButton.setFont(font)
        self.RefreshButton.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.RefreshButton.setStyleSheet("border-radius: 0px;")
        self.RefreshButton.setObjectName("RefreshButton")
        self.too_fast_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.too_fast_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1070, 10, 131, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Monaco")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        font.setWeight(75)
        font.setStrikeOut(False)
        self.too_fast_label.setFont(font)
        self.too_fast_label.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
        self.too_fast_label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter|QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        self.too_fast_label.setObjectName("too_fast_label")
        self.message_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.message_button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(310, 340, 251, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Monaco")
        self.message_button.setFont(font)
        self.message_button.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.message_button.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.message_button.setStyleSheet("")
        self.message_button.setText("")
        self.message_button.setObjectName("message_button")
        self.scroll = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self.centralwidget)
        self.scroll.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 60, 261, 631))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Monaco")
        self.scroll.setFont(font)
        self.scroll.setWidgetResizable(False)
        self.scroll.setObjectName("scroll")
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 259, 629))
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents")
        self.scroll.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.copy_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.copy_button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(340, 10, 671, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Monaco")
        font.setPointSize(25)
        self.copy_button.setFont(font)
        self.copy_button.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.copy_button.setToolTip("")
        self.copy_button.setToolTipDuration(-1)
        self.copy_button.setWhatsThis("")
        self.copy_button.setAccessibleName("")
        self.copy_button.setAccessibleDescription("")
        self.copy_button.setStyleSheet("*{\n"
"    background-color: rgba(10, 0, 0, 0);\n"
"}\n"
"*:hover{\n"
"    color:blue;\n"
"}")
        self.copy_button.setText("")
        self.copy_button.setObjectName("copy_button")
        Temp_Mail.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(Temp_Mail)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Temp_Mail)

    def retranslateUi(self, Temp_Mail):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Temp_Mail.setWindowTitle(_translate("Temp_Mail", "Temp_Mail"))
        self.Inbox_text.setText(_translate("Temp_Mail", "Inbox messages:"))
        self.RefreshButton.setToolTip(_translate("Temp_Mail", "Get new mail"))
        self.RefreshButton.setText(_translate("Temp_Mail", ""))
        self.too_fast_label.setText(_translate("Temp_Mail", "Too fast!"))


class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_Temp_Mail):
    def __init__(self):
        self.clear_cache()
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.too_fast_label.setText('')
        self.mail = Email()
        self.mail.register(password="nonepassword")
        param = {
            "address": self.mail.address,
            "password": "nonepassword"
            }
        r = requests.post('https://api.mail.tm/token', json=param)
        x = json.dumps(r.json())
        y = json.loads(x)
        self.copy_button.setText(self.mail.address)
        self.proc_exec = False
        self.message_count = 0
        self.check_proccess = threading.Thread(target=self.check_messages, args=(self.mail.address,), daemon=True)
        self.check_proccess.start()
        self.message_button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.show_message('test.html'))
        self.copy_button.clicked.connect(self.copy)
        self.copy_button.setToolTip('Click To Copy!')
        self.RefreshButton.clicked.connect(self.refresh)
        self.widget = QWidget()                 
        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scroll.setWidget(self.widget)  
    
    def check_messages(self, mail):
        while True:
            if self.proc_exec == False:
                address = mail
                param = {
                        "address": address,
                        "password": "nonepassword"
                    }
                r = requests.post('https://api.mail.tm/token', json=param)
                x = json.dumps(r.json())
                y = json.loads(x)
                header = {
                    "authorization": f'Bearer {y["token"]}'
                }
                r = requests.get('https://api.mail.tm/messages', headers=header)
                mails = json.loads(r.text)
                if str(mails['hydra:member']) != '[]':
                    if self.message_count != len(mails['hydra:member']):
                        between = len(mails['hydra:member']) - self.message_count
                        for message in range(0, between):
                            id = mails['hydra:member'][message]['id']
                            r = requests.get(f'https://api.mail.tm/messages/{id}', headers=header)
                            x = json.dumps(r.json())
                            y = json.loads(x)
                            html = '<HTML><BODY><meta charset="utf-8">' + str(y['html'][0])[y['html'][0].find('<BODY>') + 6:]
                            with open(f'cache/{self.message_count + 1}.html', 'w') as f:
                                f.write(html)
                            self.object = QPushButton(self)
                            self.object.setText(str(self.message_count + 1))
                            self.object.clicked.connect(lambda: self.show_message(str(self.message_count + 1) + '.html'))
                            self.object.move(50, 50)
                        self.message_count += between
                else:
                    pass
            else:
                break
            time.sleep(5)


    def show_message(self, file_name):
        html_file = open('test.html', encoding='utf-8')
        path = os.path.abspath(file_name)
        print(path)
        self.textBrowser.setUrl(QUrl(f'file:{path}'))
        html_file.close()

    def refresh(self):
        try:
            self.too_fast_label.setText('')
            self.mail = Email()
            self.mail.register(password="nonepassword")
            param = {
                "address": self.mail.address,
                "password": "nonepassword"
                }
            r = requests.post('https://api.mail.tm/token', json=param)
            x = json.dumps(r.json())
            y = json.loads(x)
            self.label.setText(self.mail.address)
        except Exception:
            self.too_fast_label.setText('Too fast!')
        self.clear_cache()

    def copy(self):
        cb = QApplication.clipboard()
        cb.clear()
        cb.setText(self.mail.address)
    
    def clear_cache(self):
        shutil.rmtree('cache')
        os.mkdir('cache')

    def close(self):
        app.exec_()
        self.proc_exec = True
        self.clear_cache()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(ex.close())
```

Comment: Zet, в каком месте возникает ошибка?  Наверное ошибка возникает в этой строке `self.object = QPushButton(self)` или где? И приведите полное сообщение об ошибке.

Comment: Да она возникает в этой строчке, в момент когда я пытаю создать кнопку. Как таковой ошибки нет, но в чат выходит сообщение `QObject::setParent: Cannot set parent, new parent is in a different thread`, но и кнопка которую я хочу создать не появляется. Также я чуть подкорректировал код выше, я понял что он был чуть чуть не парвильным, от чего у вас могла выйти другая ошибка.

Comment: Zet, у меня ошибок не возникало, потому что я не могу запустить ваш код. То что вы исправили, я видел, это похоже на опечатку. Теперь по сути: Нельзя использовать объекты основного потока в дополнительных потоках, это не безопасно! Надо использовать сигналы и слоты Qt . Читаем https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html и https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html#defining-new-signals-with-pyqtsignal . Похожих вопросов на этом ресурсе много. Например это может выглядеть примерно так https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1148058 ->

Comment: -> т.е. создаете класс `class Thread(QThread):` в методе `def run(self):` которого у вас будет то что в `def check_messages(self, mail):` .  Это дополнительный поток, тут ваши тяжелые запросы. В этом классе с виджетами типа `object = QPushButton(self)` взаимодействовать нельзя. Вы тут получаете какие-то данные и передаете их в основной поток, в котором у вас будет `object = QPushButton(self)` и другие виджеты типа `self.textBrowser ...` В общем вам надо почитать, посмотреть и попробовать переделать код (б-ка threading вам не нужна). Если что-то на получится, покажите вашу попытку, поможем.